# How do I recognise an image on webpage using Python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I've created a simple Python application that uses the CV2 computer vision library to recognise a template image on a webpage.

I give the application a template image that it needs to recognise on the source image. In this case, the source image is a screenshot of the website [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and the template image is the Google search button.

**Template image**
[image: Google Search button]

I thought the application worked at first, but it's drawing the rectangle completely in the wrong place on the input (source) image. I've added a picture below of where the application located the template image.

**Result**
[image]

Here's the source code.

**Main Application Source**

```
import cv2
import numpy
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Automate:
    def __init__(self):        
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("kiosk")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager("93.0.4577.63").install(), options=chrome_options)
        #self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
        self.screenShot = None
        self.finalImage = None
        
    def open_webpage(self, url):
        print(f"Open webpage {url}")
        self.driver.get(url) 

    def close_webpage(self):
        Event().wait(5)
        self.driver.close()
        print("Closing webpage")

    def snap_screen(self):
        print("Capturing screen")
        self.screenShot = "screenshot.png"
        self.driver.save_screenshot(self.screenShot)
        print("done.")
    
    def match(self, image, template):
        # convert images to greyscale.
        src = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        temp = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(template), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow("out", temp)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        height, width = src.shape
        H, W = temp.shape
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(src, temp, cv2.cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
        location = maxLoc
        bottomRight = (location[0] + W, location[1] + H)
        src2 = cv2.imread(image)
        cv2.rectangle(src2, location, bottomRight, (0, 0, 255), 5)
        cv2.imshow("output", src2)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    url = "http://www.google.com"
    auto = Automate()
    auto.open_webpage(url)
    auto.snap_screen()
    auto.close_webpage()
    match_image = "images/templates/google-button.png"

    # Match screenshot with template image.
    auto.check_match(
        image=auto.screenShot,
        template=match_image
    )
```

I'd appreciate any help or advice on how to solve this issue.

**Update**

Following the advice given by user zteffi, I resized my template image to the correct image dimensions. After doing this, the match template function works as expected.

You want to make sure that your template image is a close as possible to the actual size of the image you want to be located in the base image. In my case, this was around 150 x 150 or 200 x 200 so that it will be easier to find the button.

[image]

Comment: post the data as well (not optional). visualize `result`. use matplotlib for that, or divide by its maximum (and make sure it's of type float) before calling `imshow`

Comment: `matchTemplate()` relies on same dimensions between template and the target. Yours clearly don't match. If your templates are consistent you can adjust ChromeDriverManager's settings, otherwise you'll need to use a more robust method, for instance Feature Matching.

Comment: hey, @zteffi thanks for the advice about the image dimensions. I got it to work by resizing the template image to the correct dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resized my template image to the correct image dimensions. After doing this, the match template function works as expected.

You want to make sure that your template image is a close as possible to the actual size of the image you want to be located in the base image. In my case, this was around 150 x 150 or 200 x 200 so that it will be easier to find the button.